# Ruby script using Watir-webdriver on Apache web server or from JRuby

Tags: ruby, tomcat, jruby, watir-webdriver

I have a requirement to run a ruby script which includes the 'watir-webdriver' gem for automated browser testing. I would like to know the following:

1. If there is an option to run a ruby script on the apache web server without using ruby rails, and if so please show me how it can be achieved.
2. Using Jruby is an option to run a ruby script from the apache web server,but apparently Jruby does not have support for 'watir- webdriver'. So is there any way to run a ruby script using watir driver called from the web server?

Comment: Are you asking how to run a Ruby script on a server that does not have Ruby installed?

Comment: Ruby and watir-webdriver does not care (or jruby for that matter) which app server is serving up the application.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think watir-webdriver gem does not work with JRuby? I have just tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: could u provide any links or help of how to use watir-webdriver with jruby. I have created a java program and added the jruby and bsf jar to the project build path, this way i'm able to run a ruby script but the use to watir-web driver gives this error:                                                            require': no such file to load -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)

Comment: Maybe you just need to add this to the top of the file: `require "rubygems"`. This is all I know about installing Watir: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/tree/master/installation